# iOS blur shadow effect with image color

Tags: ios, swift, shadow, blur

What is the best way to achieve the desired effect in Swift?

I want to have a shadow of the same color as image card.

I've tried using UIVisualEffectView below UIImageView but without success.

Comment: Why my question is being downgraded?

Answer (score 0):

just found this library, see if this one helps.

[ShadowImageView](https://github.com/olddonkey/ShadowImageView)

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. While this library *may* solve the issue, no information has been included and links can go dead. Please review [answer].